# How to bind the src of an image to ng-model and extract it in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, image, angular-ngmodel

I want to bind the source of an image to the source of another image.

[image: visual example]

In the end result, the source of the large image should be bound to the src of the clicked smaller (thumbnail) image. Is this possible using ng-model?

Here's what I've got

```
        <div>
            <img ng-src="{{selectedImg.src}}">
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul ng-repeat="thumb in franchises">
                <li>
                    <img ng-src="{{thumb.images[0].list}}" ng-model="selectedImg">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do it using ng-click:

```
<div>
    <img ng-src="{{selectedImg.src}}" alt="{{slide.images[0].list}}">
</div>

<div>
    <ul ng-repeat="thumb in franchises">
        <li>
            <img ng-src="{{thumb.images[0].list}}" 
                 alt="{{thumb.images[0].list}}" 
                 ng-click="selectedImg.src = thumb.images[0].list" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But you have to define selectedImg as an object in your controller like this:

```
$scope.selectedImg = {};
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. The thing is when this initializes, the large image is empty and only gets filled when a small one is clicked. How do I set this initial property?

Comment: You could assign any item from the franchises array to the **$scope.selectedImg.src** property. For example, if you want to show the first image from franchises, you could initialize **$scope.selectedImg** like this:
    $scope.selectedImg = {src: $scope.franchises[0].images[0].list };

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, according to Angular Docs, you can only bind inputs, selects and textareas with ng-model, or a custom form control.

What you probably want to do is this:   (which is just what Saulo Lozano did with ng-click)

https://jsfiddle.net/4fz4nx1k/2/

```
<img ng-src="{{thumb.images[0].list}}" ng-click="selectedImg.src = thumb.images[0].list" >
```

So you can't really bind an img with an ng-model that way. Besides, if you could put an ng-model inside of an ng-repeat you would get the same "model value" in all of the repeated values of the ng-repeat collection.